# javascript regex match x but not \x

Tags: javascript, regex-lookarounds

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wQ3iV0/1)

The pattern is match correct part in test string:

```
1. {key1|this is main content}
2. {key29|you are the best}
3. {key3|}
```

And now I want to insert \{,\} and \| in the content, like this :

test string :

```
niyou{key1|this is \{main\} content}, match {key29|you are the best}group{key3|\|}no need to do.
```

And I hope the three part still can be matched correct :

```
1. {key1|this is \{main\} content}
2. {key29|you are the best}
3. {key3|\|}
```

How to change the regex pattern to fit this requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\{(\w+\d*)\|([^\{\}\|]*[\w\{\}\\\s|]*)\}`.

Comment: How do you expect it to work? It does work in the way your question asks it to.

Comment: so sorry, my english is so bad, I don't know how to make a clear expression

Comment: Do you want that just the third part, ie {key3|\|} can be matched and not the first two?

Comment: hmm~~, I want to match not only {xxx|xxxxxxxxx} but also {xxx|xxxx\{xx\}xxxx\|xxx}.